# How do I get a PictureBox.Image into a PrintPreviewDialog?

Tags: c#, picturebox, print-preview

I keep searching for an answer here, but all I'm finding is how to print an image, not how to get the image into a `printPreviewDialog`. It should be simple enough:

```
    private void printPreviewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = pictureBoxMain.Image; 
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();      
    }
```

However, I get the error

> `"Cannot implicitly convert type
>     'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument'"`.

There is no built in `"Convert"` that handles this conversion.  So, how do I do a simple print preview from a pictureBox?

EDIT:  Okay, print preview is working now.  Print is not working.  One issue that concerns me is that I do not have an "OK" option in my print dialog box, I have "apply", "cancel", and "print".  Visual Studio won't accept DialogResult.Print as an acceptable response (compiler error).  Here's my code at the moment, recommendations are welcomed, I'm obviously not quite getting this. Thanks

```
//Working now    
private void printPreviewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument1.DocumentName = pictureBoxMain.Image.ToString();
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDialog1.Document;   
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();      
    }

//Not printing 
private void printToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument1.OriginAtMargins = true;
        printDocument1.DocumentName = pictureBoxMain.Image.ToString();
        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  
            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;        
    }

//If this is needed, I cannot find a way to call this from within the print menu click event without generating an error, EventArgs e does not get along with PrintPageEventArgs e.  
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBoxMain.Image, 0, 0);
    }
```

EDIT: I tried making the following change to test whether the issue is the lack of an OK button.  It still didn't print.  So I don't think the lack of an OK button is the issue.

```
 if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)  
     printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
```

Thank you

Comment: The preview is just that: A preview to the printed page. so you need to code the printPage event. there you can do a drawimage with the image in the picturebox..  Or put the other way: Getting a Preview is not any 'simpler' than the real printing, it is the very same code!

Comment: Okay so I would do the printPage in order to print with the printDialog, thank you.  But how would I get the drawimage from that method into the printPreviewDialog method?

Comment: The preview will __use the printpage event__ to create the preview.